# memset causes array underflow, how to detect that

Tags: c, static-analysis

Lately I have noticed this kind of bug:

```
#define ELEMENTS 20
BOOL array[ELEMENTS];

void foo()
{
memset(array,0, ELEMENTS); /* BOOL isn't 1 byte but 4 bytes long */
}
```

How to detect memset underflows? Most of static,dynamic analysers can find only overflows. One which is able is PVSStudio. http://www.viva64.com/en/d/0101/print/.

Any free/open source alternatives ( preferably Windows but Linux also can be )?
Visual Studio 2012 analysis - failed.
Clang analyzer - failed.
Cppcheck - failed.

Comment: Valgrind (memcheck) would detect it if you read from the uninitialized values at the end of the array.

Comment: What do you think is invalid about the code you shared?  How is an analyzer supposed to know that you don't come in and fill the uninitialized portion later?  It is perfectly valid to defer (possibly indefinitely) the initialization of data; the only problem is if you try to *use* the uninitialized information...that would be   undefined behavior, and as @dohashi says, you can use valgrind for that.

Comment: @dohashi Unless the snippet in the question is in another function and thus features nested functions (which is not standard C but a compiler extension), `array` is not uninitialized at the end.

Comment: Also there is no indication at http://www.viva64.com/en/d/0101/print/ that PVSStudio detects any problem when `array` is a global variable as we have to assume it is in your example. Is this something that you verified yourself, or just an impression you get from the webpage (which is slightly different from your example)?

Comment: Ok you are right. I was reading http://www.viva64.com/en/examples/V512/ and there are examples. I wrongly assumed that same of the arrays are global, but now I think they are just members of the class.

Comment: So, can Valgrind (memcheck) really warn about reading uninitialized global data even it's is totaly correct? I don't want to rely on assured by C standard - implicit initialization of all global data to '0' .

Comment: "*reading uninitialized*" never is correct. "*global data*" is always initialised automatical on the program's start-up. Valgrins' tool "memcheck" only tests the access to the heap.

Comment: "*I don't want to rely on assured by C standard - implicit initialization of all global data to '0'*" then explicitly initialise your global data on definition.

Comment: Here is an example: https://godbolt.org/z/hen3Kn

Answer (score 3):

You cannot detect this without external tools like Valgrind, but you can avoid the need to detect it.

Scale to the size of the array's element:

```
memset(array, 0, ELEMENTS * sizeof array[0]);
```

Or if you can make sure `array` isn't a pointer (as per your code snippet) just do:

```
memset(array, 0, sizeof array);
```

The most simple way to avoid this is to consequently initialise **all** variables on definition:

```
BOOL array[ELEMENTS] = {0};
```

Comment: excessive superfluous parentheses detected: `sizeof` is an operator.

Comment: "*excessive*"? ;-) @Deduplicator

Comment: Anyway, that does not answer the question "How to detect that possible logic-failure?", though you certainly show what code should have been there, as well as mentioning that it's not an error, unless a later error which can be detected is also made.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Nicened.